# RSpec won't execute tagged tests when using RSpec::Core::Runner.run

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to execute RSpec tests programatically using `RSpec::Core::Runner.run`. I can run individual spec files:

```
args = %w(-r spec_helper --order defined --format CustomFormatter --format documentation ./spec/Tests_spec.rb)
RSpec::Core::Runner.run(args)
```

But when I try and run a tagged test I am told everything is filtered out

```
it "example I'm working now", :focus => true do; end
```

```
args = %w(-r spec_helper --order defined --format CustomFormatter --format documentation --tag focus)
RSpec::Core::Runner.run(args)
```

```
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

All examples were filtered out
```

Do tags not work when executing tests via Runner?  Thanks!

Comment: It does not appear that you specified any test files in `args`? Maybe try `%w(-r spec_helper --order defined --format CustomFormatter --format documentation --tag focus ./spec)`

Comment: That was it!  Thanks!  Interesting though, when I called these tests from the command line I didn't have to include `./spec`.  But hey, it's working now!

Comment: By Default the rspec command line tool assumes as default path of `spec`, when you call it without a path it will merge this default into the `args`. [Docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/configuration/setting-the-default-spec-path) When calling the `Runner` directly this does not occur and thus you will need to specify the path.